# Permission issue in linux

Tags: linux

I have changed permission of `/run/user` to `777`.
But when the machine got reboot permission changed to `754`.

How we can make permission of `/run/user` to `777` permanently?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: so that other user can also perform read write operation,,,,,,,,In tmpfs these operation are faster.

Comment: Yes, but it gets cleared at every system reboot because they are in the memory. How about using a startup script? What flavor or linux are you using?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I hope linux option is there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This isn't permanent, but it's going to look like it is. You can put the command

```
sudo chmod 777 /run/user
```

in your *rc.local* file, found in */etc/rc.local* .

This will run your command on boot and change the permissions.

Note: if you want to change the permissions of everything inside the user folder use **-R** option to do it recursively, as:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /run/user
```